# User join server doesn't work. discord.py

Tags: python, discord

I'm making a bot that welcomes people to my server and its not working at all. the bot just does nothing when a user joined. Pls help.

```
client.event
async def on_member_join(memeber):
    print("member joined")
    guild = client.get_guild(SERVER ID HERE)
    channel = guild.get_channel(CHANNEL ID) 

    await channel.send(f"Welcome to the server {memeber.mention}!")
```

I gave it the permission server members intent and this is my code for it. I also enabled it on the dev portal.

```
intent = discord.Intents.default() 
intent.members = True 
client = Bot(command_prefix="!", intents = intent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't attach the event correctly. It is a decorator. You forgot the `@` that attaches the decorator to the function.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(memeber):
    print("member joined")
    guild = member.guild # Just get guild from member
    channel = guild.get_channel(channel.id)
    await channel.send(f"Welcome to the server {memeber.mention}!")
```

Comment: thx but now it says: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_channel'` what attribute should I use instead?

Comment: @No-Question123 Are you using `channel id` with a space in between?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: no. im using the actual channel and server id there. i Updated my question to be more clear. @12944qwerty

Comment: @No-Question123 I've updated my answer. Sorry about that

Comment: i used your answer to do this but i ran into a couple problems. it says that channel isnt defined in the `channel.id`. when i put channel in the agrgumets for `acync` it says its missing positional argument channel. trying to hard code the channel id doesnt work either cuz the  it says that guild has no attribute to `get_channel`. @12944qwerty

Comment: @No-Question123 The channel Id is the channel ID from your question....

Comment: right but when i try using the hard codded channel id it just gives me an attribute error:
`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_channel'` @12944qwerty

Comment: @No-Question123 you didn't get guild right, is it exactly like in my answer?

Comment: my bad. i made some mistakes in my code but it works now thx so mutch!!!